# User to User notifications not working firebase (index.js file)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I want to monitor when the notification tree of each user is changed , and send them a notification. A notification has an action and username that is the only thing needed for the notification

I am using nodejs and npm after configuring firebase tools I have deployed this file to my firebase console. No I have never used js in my life

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');

let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

 exports.sendNotification = . 
functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/notifications').onWrite((event) 
=> {

const uid = event.params.uid

if (!event.data.val()){
return console.log('User' , uid)
}

  const getDeviceTokensPromise = 



admin.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/notificationToken`).once('value');
  const getUserWithUid = admin.auth().getUser(uid);  

  return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getUserWithUid]).then((results) => {
const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
const user = results[1];

// Check if there are any device tokens.
    if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
      return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send 
to.');
}
console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');
console.log('Fetched follower profile', follower);

    // Notification details.
    const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: `${user.username}`,
    body: `${user.action} `,

  },
};

// Listing all tokens.
const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    // Send notifications to all tokens.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
  }).then((response) => {
    // For each message check if there was an error.
    const tokensToRemove = [];
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
      const error = result.error;
      if (error) {
    console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], 
error);
    // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
    if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || 
error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {



tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
        }
      }
    });
    return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
  });

});
```

here is a screen shot of my data base:

[image: database]

here is how i obtain the "notificationToken" value that is stored in FB :

```
(Messaging.messaging().fcmToken)!
```

how I subscribe to notification:

```
        messaging.subscribe(toTopic: "users/\(uid)/notifications")
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is screen shot of log:

[image]

Comment: What isn't working about the code? Is your Cloud Function being triggered? Does it load the tokens from the database correctly? Are there any errors showing in the log? Did you try [triggering it in the Cloud Functions emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_realtime_database_functions) to see what happens?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen see my edit , cheers mate not sure if it is loading tokens correctly or if I am using the correct token to be more clear , the cloud functions are not being triggered and notifications are not being send or received

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the tokens are not stored in the database the way your code expects.  The tokens need to be stored as children of `notificationToken` with the token being the **key**, not the value.  The value is not used and can be anything, e.g. `true`.  For an example, see the [Cloud Functions sample documentation](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications#sample-database-structure):

```
/users
    /Uid-12345
        displayName: "Bob Dole"
        /notificationTokens
            1234567890: true // <= NOTE: the key is the token
        photoURL: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/..."
```